# ASP .Net Web API And RavenDB Compatibility

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ravendb

I use RavenDB Build 1.0.960 and ASP .Net Web API in separated assemblies. My application can not serialize and deserialize json in run-time.

Is any solution to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common complaint that we hear about RavenDB 1.0 is that it depends on Newtonsoft.Json 4.0.8, while many libraries are already using 4.5.7. We already resolved the problem once and for all in the RavenDB 1.2 branch, but that is a few months from going live yet.

Therefor, we create a new nuget package: http://nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.Client/1.0.971

This nuget package is the exact same as 960, except that we compiled it against Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.7. Note that this is only supported for the client mode, if you want to run RavenDB Server or RavenDB Embedded, it is still going to require Newtonsoft.Json 4.0.8 in the 1.0 version.

The main idea is that you can get to run against RavenDB Server using Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.7 on the client side, which is the most common scenario for RavenDB.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You shouldn't just give a link to another site as an answer, since the site may go out of date in the future. Instead, click the "edit" link on this answer and include the essential parts of the solution from that page here. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259

Comment: I would be **a lot better** of you could also tell us something  about what the solution is. Not just that there is one.

Comment: George - Is there also a build of the Raven.Client.MvcIntegration library that uses the Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.7? I'm experiencing a strange issue using the unstable build (in order to get around the same Newtonsoft compatibility problems) which I think 971 will negate.  I need to use the Profiler to confirm. Is there a build out there that I can use? I hope so.